How can I install gcc10 in amazon linux 2023?
I am trying to install the NVIDIA driver and Cuda toolkit but it expects gcc10. Using p2.xlarge which has Tesla k80. And Tesla k80 supports Cuda toolkit 11.4 (https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/). Then from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version, it says that Cuda toolkit 11.4 requires gcc10.
When I installed gcc using sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools", it gave me gcc11.
And AWS documentation says Amazon Linux 2023 does not support EPEL (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/linux/al2023/ug/compare-with-al2.html#epel)
Is there any easy way to install gcc10, without building it from source?

This question is for installing using some package manager or without building from sources.

You don't need gcc10. You can install NVidia drivers using dnf. See this re:Post.
The steps are as follows for folks who don't want to read it:
sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/amzn2023/x86_64/cuda-amzn2023.repo
sudo dnf module install -y nvidia-driver:latest-dkms
sudo dnf install -y cuda-toolkit
sudo reboot

